# how to get amount of each day in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

the field time has entries like `2013-09-02 07:54:28` and i want to get the amount of each day. in pseudoscript it would work like this:

1. delete hours
2. find date in array if not exist write date
3. add amount +1 to date in array
4. proceed to next result

an entry like mentioned above with a number in the array i get through this:

```
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT time FROM stats WHERE seite = '2'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $all[] = $row["time"];
}
print_r($all);
```

Comment: print_r results: Array ( [0] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [3] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [4] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ...  [19] => 2013-07-15 23:04:18 [20] => 2013-07-15 23:05:22 ...

Comment: Why not just do it in the query with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Barmar: maybe he is doing something else in the loop. If not, then `GROUP BY` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing some other logic in the loop:

```
$all = array();
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT time, DATE(time) AS timeDate FROM stats WHERE seite = '2'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if (!isset($all[$row['timeDate']])) {
        $all[$row['timeDate']] = 0;
    }
    $all[$row['timeDate']]++;
    // other logic
}
print_r($all);
```

Or if this is the whole logic, just to calculate same dates :

```
$all = array();
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT DATE(time) AS timeDate, COUNT(time) timeCount FROM stats WHERE seite = '2' GROUP BY DATE(time)");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $all[$row['timeDate']] = $row['timeCount'];
}
print_r($all);
```

Comment: thanks, but this results in: Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context...

Comment: I changed the code, so SQL already returns formated date (no need to format date in php).

Answer (score 0):

You can find ammount by SQL query without processing by php.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') AS day, COUNT(*) AS amount FROM stats WHERE seite = '2' GROUP BY day;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT date(time), count(time) FROM stats WHERE seite = '2'  group by date(time)`